# Validate that a method does not change from being void into return $something

Tags: c#, moq

Is it possible with Moq to make sure, that a method that is currently "returning" void stays that way?

Consider this simple class with one method:

```cs
public class SomeClass {
    public virtual void CreateEntry(SomeEntryModel model) {
        // Create some entry
    }
}
```

Which later on in development gets changed to return `Guid` instead of `void`:

```cs
public class SomeClass {
    public virtual Guid CreateEntry(SomeEntryModel model) {
        // Create some entry
        return System.Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

So to verify that the `void` method gets called i would do basically this:

```
var mock = new Mock<SomeClass>();
mock.Setup(m => m.CreateEntry(It.IsAny<SomeEntryModel>())).Verifiable();
// call the SUT
mock.Verify();
```

But this would not raise any errors when the `CreateEntry` method silently transitions from returning `void` into `Guid`. Is this possible to validate with Mock? Or do i need to use reflections myself in this case?

Comment: I don't really see how `Moq` is related to this: the way to test this is using reflection (but I have serious questions as to *why* you're putting this in a unit test...)

Comment: Write a unit test that looks for the method using reflection and checks it doesn't have a return type.

Comment: @canton7 because the unit tests also "strap down" the behavior of your unit? Just like validating "does throw" or "does not throw" does. So why not making sure, that some years later somebody just changes the return type from `void` to `Guid`. Because this doe not give you any compiler errors/warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in functionality to determine whether the method returns `void` or some other type.

```
typeof(SomeClass).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "CreateEntry").ReturnType == typeof(void)
```

Or, if you have to get type from a class instance, you can use the `GetType()` method.

```
SomeClass mySomeClassInstance;
<...>
mySomeClassInstance.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "CreateEntry").ReturnType == typeof(void)
```

Comment: Don't use `FirstOrDefault` and then assume the result is not null. If you expect there to be at least one match, use `First`. If you expect there to only be a single match, use `Single`

Comment: Also, there are overloads of `GetMethod` which takes the method name -- that's going to be cheaper and cleaner than fetching all methods and then searching through them

Comment: As stated in the original question: "Or do i need to use reflections myself in this case?" i already know how to do it via reflections. ;) I just wonder if Mock provides something like 
 `.ReturnsVoid()` (And i also know how to write an extension method for Mock. But why writing even a single line yourself if a library provides the functionality you need? ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this using TDD. If you know you're changing the method like this, update your tests to suit, observe them go red, then update the implementation. Asserting for void as a general rule seems like it'd add a maintenance overhead when writing your tests.

Comment: Well, you describe what we do on a daily basis. The missing part ist: Does Mock allow me to check for return type void? Or do i have todo the heavy lifting myself via reflections?